# PowerShell Register-PSRepository Set Priority

Tags: powershell, powershellget

I have two PowerShell Repositories installed. It isn't possible to uninstall the default package feed (https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/) with the *Unregister-PSRepository* command, and I don't want to get my packages over the default package feed. Is it somehow possible to set a priority over which package feed the packages will be installed?